# Ускорить двойной запрос

Tags: производительность, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM notifications INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = notifications.from INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.vk_id = notifications.to WHERE notifications.npoints > 0 AND notifications.history = 1 AND (notifications.to = $user_vk_id OR notifications.from = $user_vk_id) ORDER BY notifications.id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Медленно выполняется запрос, хоть и индексы стоят там, где нужно. В таблице 3 млн записей.

Comment: у вас их еще много этих медленных запросов (просто интересно)? такое ощещение, что вы не читаете ответы на предыдущие свои вопросы, или думаете что-то новое расскажут именно для этого конкретного запроса? имхо, все кто хотел уже высказались...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, все которые были медленными, благодаря ХэшКоду исправил. Этот остался единственный неисправимый...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT ALL - это зло, выведите только необходимые поля;
 План запроса необходимо проанализировать, то что я напишу всего лишь догадки и не много рефакторинга.
Notifications.to,  Notifications.from - надеюсь есть индексы (по ним идет условие)

(notifications.to = $user_vk_id OR notifications.from = $user_vk_id)
можно разбить на два запроса с UNION ALL
Селективность та же по таблице users, соединять меньшее количество таблиц
То есть

```
SELECT ... FROM 
(
SELECT ... FROM <TableList>
WHERE  notifications.to = $user_vk_id
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM <TableList>
WHERE  notifications.from = $user_vk_id
)
ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 5
```